# No value given for one or more required parameters. in asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

**am trying to get the column values from a grid view when a row is checked and insert those values into some other table ,
             here is my c # code when a check box in grid view is selected**

```cs
    protected void chkfun_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox chkstatus = (CheckBox)sender;
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)chkstatus.NamingContainer;
        }
     protected void hidebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection acc = dc_object.a_object.Connect("CARLI_funds_FY16");
            OleDbCommand commd = new OleDbCommand();
            commd.Connection = acc;
            CheckBox x1;
            HiddenField x2;
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                x1 = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("chkfun") as CheckBox;
                if (x1.Checked)
                {
                    x2 = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("hdnfld") as HiddenField;
                    var fund_code = (GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblfundcode") as Label).Text;
                    var fund_name = (GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblfundname") as Label).Text;

                    commd.CommandText = "insert into funds_hidden values(fund_code,fund_name)";
                commd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

            }
            acc.Close();
            Response.Redirect("allfunds.aspx");
        }
```

**and here is my code for aspx**

```cs
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID,FUND_CODE,FUND_NAME" AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkheader" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkheader_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True" />
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkfun" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkfun_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True" />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnfld" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("ID") %>'/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FUND_CODE">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblfundcode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FUND_CODE") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FUND_NAME">
                        <ItemTemplate>`enter code here`
                        <asp:Label ID="lblfundname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FUND_NAME") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="hidebutton" runat="server" OnClick="hidebutton_Click" Text="hide" />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" SortParameterName="" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT ID,NORMAL_FUND_NAME AS FUND_NAME, NORMAL_FUND_CODE AS FUND_CODE FROM funds_sample1 WHERE (LEDGER_ID = 43) AND (PARENT_FUND = 1124 OR PARENT_FUND = 984 OR PARENT_FUND = 370 OR PARENT_FUND = 363)"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </form>
```

*am just beginner please guide me if there are any mistakes in my code and what should i do to clear this error, thanks in advance*

Comment: you need to look up how to do a paramerized query specifically look up `OleDbCommand.Parameters` for examples on msdn C# plenty of working examples there as well as on the internet.. the error message states clearly what the issue is.. you need to supply parameter names plus the values for the 2 parameter you need a where clause probably here as well `commd.CommandText = "insert into funds_hidden values(fund_code,fund_name)";`

Answer (score 1):

You should be specifying parameters for your values:

```
commd.CommandText = "insert into funds_hidden values(?, ?)";
commd.Parameters.Add("code", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = fund_code;
commd.Parameters.Add("name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = fund_name;
```

I'd also recommend:

- Learning about C# naming conventions (use camelCase rather than underscore_separators)
- Using a `using` statement for database resources (such as the command and connection)
- Specifying the field names you want to update in your SQL statement

Comment: yes thank you very much @Jon  that works perfect and i will learn about them too

Answer (score 0):

**i have changed my insert statement to the following way to make it work ,thanks for helping its working now**

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            x1 = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("chkfun") as CheckBox;
            if (x1.Checked)
            {
                x2 = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("hdnfld") as HiddenField;
                var fund_code = (GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblfundcode") as Label).Text;
                var fund_name = (GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblfundname") as Label).Text;

                string insertstatement = "insert into funds_hidden(fund_code,fund_name)"+ " values (?,?)" ;

                OleDbCommand insertcommand = new OleDbCommand(insertstatement, acc);
                insertcommand.Parameters.Add("fund_code", OleDbType.Char).Value = fund_code;
                insertcommand.Parameters.Add("fund_name", OleDbType.Char).Value = fund_name;
insertcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```